# What is the purpose of an "integration branch"?

Tags: git, git-branch

If a branching strategy consists of *n* feature branches, a "master" (mainline) and an "integration" branch. What is the purpose of the integration branch? Why can testing and integration not be performed on the feature branch itself?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because it's a feature branch. It should only contain changes pertaining to the one feature. The integration branch is where you bring multiple features together for testing, before the final push onto master.

Of course, you don't *have* to separate things this way. You *could* do integration on feature branches, just as you *could* do all your work on master. But separation of concerns is a good thing.

Comment: What is a typical workflow using this branching strategy? Get the code "developer complete" on the feature branch and move to the integration branch to create a release for QA?

Comment: @Ben: Basically, yes. The first step, though, would be to merge the with the latest changes in master, especially if the feature has been underway for some time. Actually, the feature should regularly merge from master to avoid big bad merges at the end. Also note that there doesn't have to be a single definitive integration branch. One integration branch can serve to merge some features for version *x*, while a different integration branch is simultaneously used to collate a series of bugfixes for version *x* - 1. In short, branching should mirror your workflow — nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: once development has moved to the integration branch, under what circumstances would further commits be made to the feature branch?

Comment: @Ben: Development should never move to the integration branch. Work on a feature stays on the feature branch. If this happens after you've merged onto an integration branch, then you simply merge again. Note, however, that I use the term "feature" in a finite project-oriented way; work on the feature should eventually come to an end as the feature is completed and becomes part of the core product. This generally occurs when the integration branch is merged to master. Any work after that should be either a bug-fix to the core, or a new feature branch.

Comment: so any fixes arising out of QA testing are applied to the feature branch and then pulled into the integration branch for further QA releases? Once QA is happy, the integration branch is pulled into trunk and the integration branch and feature branches are deleted?

Answer (score 9):

To be a bit more specific on why exactly "separation is good": The purpose of the integration branch is to determine whether new features work not only on their own, but also in combination with other new features. This means that they might not, the features might cause conflicts that take a while to resolve.

However, you still might want to start deploying a subset of the new features to the mainline branch, so you don't block all features because an incompatibility between two of them.

Now, if you had already merged feature branches into one another, you will have a hard time merging them separately into the mainline. It's not entirely impossible, but it's certainly a hassle (I have tried).

If your feature branches contain major code churns, or if they overlap significantly with regard to the areas of code that is being worked on, you may even want to take this idea further, and have branches that integrate two features before merging them anywhere else, including the global integration branch, i. e. have multiple levels of integration. Of course, this is generally not a desirable situation, but you may not be able to avoid it, and the resulting conflicts can be a lot easier to resolve if you are generous with integration branches.

Answer (score 3):

One major reason i often see for the need for an "integration" branch is when your feature branches are untestable on their own.  In my experience, this usually is due to a database dependency.  Or, consider a website project that is database backed... lets say its a JSP application hosted in BEA Weblogic, back by a 60GB Oracle database; It would take a LOT of hardware to give each feature branch its own BEA Weblogic and Oracle instance to test from.  Instead, it is generally easier to develop as best as possible into a feature branch, but move into an integration branch for full QA testing, where QA needs to be performed on a full web server and database.